# Separate values of two properties into dynamic excel columns and remove duplicates

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am creating an inventory script for my team and the end goal is to gather monitor information of multiple computers provided from a list. The output results in an excel sheet with a table.

My problem is, I would like to have the monitor models exported into dynamic columns for each monitor, such as "Monitor1", "Monitor2", etc.

Another issue I am having is there are duplicate monitor models with the same serial number that will populate as well.

I've tried other solutions such as Get-CimInstance, Get-PnPDevice, etc. but the results from those will only provide "Generic PnP Monitor", etc. I am using "Get-WmiObject -Class WmiMonitorID" because this has been the only way I have seen that will give me the exact monitor model after decoding the string. Here is my code:

```
Import-Module ImportExcel

$computersFile = "C:\Temp\Lists\MonitorInfoList.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Temp\Outputs\Results.xlsx"
$computerInfo = @()
$computers = Get-Content $computersFile


foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    try {
        $info = @{
            "Workstation ID" = $computer
            "Screen" = $null
            "MSerial" = $null
        }

        ####Irrelevant code...####

        $monitorInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class WmiMonitorID -Namespace "root\wmi" -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        foreach ($monitor in $monitorInfo) {
        $Monitor_Models = $monitorInfo | ForEach-Object { [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.UserFriendlyName -ne 0) }
        $Monitor_Serials = $monitorInfo | ForEach-Object { [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($_.SerialNumberID -ne 0) }
            
        } 
        $info.Screen = $Monitor_Models -join ', '
        $info.MSerial = $Monitor_Serials -join ', '


        ####Irrelevant code...####

        $computerInfo += New-Object PSObject -Property $info
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve information for computer: $computer. Exception: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

$desiredProperties = "Workstation ID", "Screen", "MSerial"

$computerInfo = $computerInfo | Sort-Object -Property ComputerName
$computerInfo = $computerInfo | Select-Object $desiredProperties

$computerInfo | Export-Excel -Path $outputFile -AutoSize -TableStyle Light16
```

I currently have the information output like this for two computers:

| Workstation ID | Screen | MSerial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Computer1 | BenQ BL2283, **MDCC-6230, MDCC-6230** | Serial1, **Serial2, Serial2** |
| Computer2 | AS224WMi | Serial1 |

How do I get the output to remove the duplicate models and serial numbers, and dynamically create new columns for each monitor/serial number? Such as:

| Workstation ID | Screen1 | Screen2 | MSerial1 | MSerial2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer1 | BenQ BL2283 | MDCC-6230 | Serial1 | Serial2 |
| Computer2 | AS224WMi | Serial1 | Serial1 |  |

Comment: Is 2 the maximum number of MSerial entries? Or do you want to dynamically figure that out everytime the code runs?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I would like for it to figure out whenever the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the maximum number of screens and serials for any individual machine, then use that to generate the list of `$desiredProperties` passed to `Select-Object` before exporting to Excel:

```
Import-Module ImportExcel

$computersFile = "C:\Temp\Lists\MonitorInfoList.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Temp\Outputs\Results.xlsx"
$computers = Get-Content $computersFile

# we'll use this to track the maximum counts
$maxMonitorCount = 1

# direct assignment from a flow control statement is 
# usually much more efficient than using `@() += ...`
$computerInfo = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    try {
        # we will be populating the property table dynamically, so 
        # lets make sure the properties retain their insertion order
        $info = [ordered]@{
            "Workstation ID" = $computer
        }

        ####Irrelevant code...####

        $monitorInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class WmiMonitorID -Namespace "root\wmi" -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        # keep track of local monitor count
        $monitorCount = 0

        foreach ($monitor in $monitorInfo) {
            # increment monitor count for current computer
            $monitorCount++

            # fetch the column values and assign to `$info` property table
            # 
            # NOTE: There's no need to manually remove 0's from the binary string - use the correct encoding instead
            $info["Screen${monitorCount}"] = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($monitor.UserFriendlyName)
            $info["MSerial${monitorCount}"] = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($monitor.SerialNumberID)
        }

        # remember to track the global maximum
        $maxMonitorCount = [Math]::Max($monitorCount, $maxMonitorCount)

        ####Irrelevant code...####

        # output object
        [PSCustomObject]$info
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve information for computer: $computer. Exception: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# generate the list of desired properties based on observed maximum monitor count
$desiredProperties = @(
    "Workstation ID"
    1..$maxMonitorCount |ForEach-Object { "Screen${_}" }
    1..$maxMonitorCount |ForEach-Object { "MSerial${_}" }
)

# sort data set, then select the maximum number of columns for each object
$computerInfo = $computerInfo | Sort-Object -Property "Workstation ID" | Select-Object $desiredProperties

# export to Excel
$computerInfo | Export-Excel -Path $outputFile -AutoSize -TableStyle Light16
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I noticed in the output, there are still duplicate serial numbers and monitors. How can I correlate the MSerial values with the $Screen values and remove duplicates?